# Выдаёт ошибку, AttributeError: ‘NoneType’ object has no attribute group

Tags: python

Проблема в следующем: при выгрузке бота на сервер и запуска функции, которая парсит сайты- бот выдает эту ошибку. Не могу понять в чем проблема, особенно, когда на локалке все работает корректно и не выбрасывает никакие исключения. Очевидно, что ошибка в коде питон, но почему тогда на локалке все работает исправно, парсятся сайты и вовзвращает `excel` файл, а на сервере выбрасывает такую ошибку? В чем проблема?

Код ниже:

```
with open('crypto_three.json') as file:
        templates_one = json.load(file)

for item in range(0, 20):

    title = translator.translate(templates_one['yahoo'][item]['title'], dest='ru')
    description = translator.translate(templates_one['yahoo'][item]['description'], dest='ru')
    url = templates_one['yahoo'][item]['url']
    
    titles.append(title.text)
    descriptions.append(description.text)
    urls.append(url)


    df = pd.DataFrame({'Заголовок': [title for title in titles],
                        'Описание': [description for description in descriptions],
                        'Ссылка': [url for url in urls]})
```

[image: Терминал сайта, где на сервер загружен не даёт скопировать. Выкладываю traceback, самое главное- понять, почему в vs code все работает и запускается корректно, а на сервере нет...]

Comment: Добавьте полный текст ошибки вместе с трэйсбэком

Comment: @insolor добавил скриншот, прошу прощения, но сервер не даёт скопировать из терминала, который у них на сайте представлен

Comment: Ну по ошибке похоже, что googletrans не может получить токен от гугла. Проверьте, что у вас на сервере вообще исходящие запросы в интернет не блокируются.

Comment: @insolor на сервере не у никаких ограничений.

Comment: не подскажете, как можно это исправить? первый раз на сервер что-то выгружаю.

Comment: Без понятия. Я все же уверен, что сервер что-то блокирует.

Answer (score 0):

Обновил библиотеку googletrans и проблема исчезла.

```
pip install googletrans 3.1.0a0
```

Пишут, что 3 версия с багами

Comment: К чему относится этот комментарий?  Это обновление помогло вам решить проблему, описанную в вопросе?

Comment: Абсолютно точно, обновил и проблема исчезла. Пишут, что 3 версия с багами

Comment: @Art Хорошо бы добавлять такую информацию в ответ, можно коротко описать в чем смысл обновления и добавить ссылку на где вы нашли "пишут". Добавить только  ссылку будет не корректно (может прекратить свое существование). На данный момент - это не ответ, а комментарий